# Show the progress of a large while loop in Python without slowing down the process too much

Tags: python

I have to use a very long while loop in Python, so it takes quite a while for the program to finish executing. I would like to know, while the code is running, how long the program has left to complete.

I had thought of printing the number of the iteration in progress:

```
while N > 0:
    ...
    N = N-1
    print(N, "iterations completed")
```

However, I think this may be slowing down too much the execution. Is there maybe a better option?

Comment: Use e.g. [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/). But why do you think it will slow down the execution?

Comment: Did you run some timing tests? What makes you think that a single `print` will slow down your program?

Answer (score 2):

use [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) 
an example :

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

for n in tqdm(range(N)):
    ...
   #your code.
```

or 
another library you can use [progress bar](https://github.com/verigak/progress/)

```
from progress.bar import Bar

bar = Bar('Processing', max=N)
for i in range(N):
    # Do some work
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

Comment: Can you show why this is better than using a simple `print`?

Answer (score 1):

There is [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) for this.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(N), desc='Iterations completed'):
    # do something
    pass
```

Comment: Can you show why this is better than using a simple `print`?

Comment: Yes, it's because printing spoils the outcome of `tqdm`'s output, meaning that it shows a newline in each iteration, instead of a single progress bar that the OP wants.

Comment: There are ways to overcome this using `print` (remember that behind the scenes `tqdm` simply prints...). The question asks for an efficient way. What makes this more efficient that a `print`?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that tqdm handles the printing gracefully suffy? Furthermore, the OP's code prints for every single iteration, considerably slowing down the loop.

Comment: I think that the above is the reason the OP considers his code inefficient.